# Microsoft Update - how to make it work properly?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I`m using a wide range of Microsoft products - Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with SP1 included, Microsoft Project, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010. After doing a full OS reinstall I tried using Microsoft Update to get all the latest service packs and updates, but many  of the updates (most notably the service packs) fail to install.

Is there a way of installing the software so it will succeed? I am aware that there probably are many dependencies involved and one installation breaks another, but there must be a way I can install the software properly.

Is there any particular installation order I can use? Should I run MS Update After each product is installed or install everything first and then try to update?

Comment: Did you try to restart the PC and then install the updates. Many updates need to restart the PC to install.

Comment: MS Update doesn`t ask me to restart, except for W7 updates which install properly.

Comment: Give a try with restart. And also please post a screen shot of the error.

Comment: Well, the error is just regular MS Update screen saying that some of the updates failed - The error codes are 643 for VS2010 SP1, 84BC051E for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1. The others are minor security updates which don`t bother me as much as service pack fails.

Comment: Please update your question with full detail of error code for VS and SQL and try to put the screen shot if you can.

Comment: I can`t, since I`m writing from another PC. The update window doesn`t show anything more than just the error code and update status, which is "failed".

Comment: When I had this problem bringing a XP system up to date from 0-3 , and having minor update issues, I could not figure why things were going wrong when it was undoubtedly tested over TIME, and there I was trying to jam it all in at once :-) Slowly and carefully I made a Image of the system, and updated By Date (in order of the releace dates), doing purposfull reboots and testing. Again imaged the system repeatedly, to insure that I could retract if something went wrong. It all went smoother than I thought it would, slowly, but surely.

Comment: If you rerun Windows update does it offer the failed updates again? Often when you are doing updates from out-of-box it will offer updates that supersede other updates.  So, for example, if it offers you IE8, and all the IE7 updates, it installs IE8 first, and so all the IE7 updates 'fail' (and they aren't offered again next time) because they don't apply anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get all (I think) the software and updates installed by installing clean W7 SP1 with only the drivers, then SQL Server, VS 2010, VS SP1 Pack (had to do it twice because it hanged the first time; strangely, after relaunching the install it skipped SP1 altogether and VS shows it as installed).

After everything was installed I launched MS Update and kept it going until all the updates got installed (I had about 10 failed updates over time, but after consistent relaunching they all got installed).